# Meteor - If Statements in .html

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor

I am using an FS Collection called "MyUploads" to store files that a user has uploaded. In the HTML, I have created a submit button. My question is, how do I create the if statement such that the submit button:

`<input type="submit" name="parseUploads">`

is visible only if the size of the collection is greater than 0?

Note-- I have created the following helper function in the .js to determine the total count (the size) of the files uploaded to the collection:

```
fileCount: function () {
  return MyUploads.find().count();
}
```

Comment: Also checkout the [spacebars docs on `{{if}}...{{/if}}` blocks](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#ifunless), the [meteor docs on Template Helpers](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Template-helpers), and some [examples in the blaze docs](http://meteor.github.io/blaze/docs.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your helper to return a boolean

```
fileCountMoreThanOne: function () {
  return MyUploads.find().count() > 0;
}
```

And use as follow:

```
{{#if fileCountMoreThanOne }}
    <input type="submit" name="parseUploads">
{{/if}}
```

Comment: + ror renaming `fileCount` so its return value follows the principle of least surprise.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But, I don't think that will solve the problem.

Comment: Nope. I added your suggested function as a helper, but the submit button does not appear. I am certain that there are no issues with the submit button because it appears when I remove the if-statement

Comment: Figured it out! Here is how the helper function:
fileCountMoreThanOne: function () {
      if(MyUploads.find().count() > 0){
        return true;
      }
  }

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your feedback was what I needed to figure out the problem :)

Comment: @RobynSilber, Good to know ... but in your solution, what if the `count` is `0`? Adding `return false;` would work. But in my solution you could change `> 1` by `> 0`

Comment: I realized after the fact that I had meant to pose my question stating that the Collection size must be greater than 0, not greater than 1. That was my mistake! Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Return a boolean

```
fileCount: function () {
  return MyUploads.find().count() > 0;
}
```

Then use

```
{{#if fileCount}}
  <input type="submit" name="parseUploads">
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately that doesn't work. Please let me know if you have any other suggestions.